# Configure Hibernate with Vaadin JPAContainer2.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, vaadin

Im trying to convert the Vaadin demo for JPAContainer to use hibernate instead of eclipselink.  But I cannot seem to get it working.

Here is the documentation I am referencing https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.html

This is the stack trace when trying to run the app:

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from   fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1004)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:978)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:801)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1365)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1293)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1375)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.DemoDataGenerator.create(DemoDataGenerator.java:55)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.JpaAddressbookApplication.<clinit>(JpaAddressbookApplication.java:11)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:978)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:801)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl    .java:169)
        org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:    67)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.DemoDataGenerator.create(DemoDataGenerator.java:55)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.JpaAddressbookApplication.<clinit>(JpaAddressbookApplication.java:11)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:978)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:801)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grails_sandbox
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
    org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.DemoDataGenerator.create(DemoDataGenerator.java:55)
com.vaadin.demo.jpaaddressbook.JpaAddressbookApplication.<clinit>(JpaAddressbookApplication.java:11)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:978)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:801)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

here is my persistence.xml located in /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="addressbook">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-update" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Shadow13" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grails_sandbox" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Ive included the hibernate library along with mysql connector in /WEB-INF/lib/

I have been messing with this almost the entire day and getting no where with it. Any helper would be appreciated.

Comment: seems to me that your driver is not include in the buildPath.

Comment: its located in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ and it shows up in my WebApp library in eclipse

Comment: How do you deploy your web application? Tomcat under Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive gotten this to work by using an earlier version of hibernate 3.x.  Originally I was using hibernate 4.x and I think there must have been some configuration changes in that version which did not allow me to use in the way I was attempting to.